# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RadioUIButton"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to create a custom `UIButton`. Here is my .h class:

```
@interface RadioUIButton : UIButton

@property (strong) NSString* stringTag;

@end
```

When I try to access the class from `FeedbackViewController.m` I get this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RadioUIButton", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FeedbackViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What I have tried so far:

> Enable Bitcode: set to NO
>
> Build Active Architecture only: set to NO

None of the above worked. What else can I try?

Comment: What does the .m file for this class look like? Is it a member of your target?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. Yes, is a member.

Comment: Please check in the build settings the „Valid Architectures“ entry. There, arm64 should be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if Target Membership is checked for that class. For your project, Select RadioUIButton.m file and check.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change below line

```
@property (strong) NSString* stringTag;
```

to

`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* stringTag;`

or

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* stringTag;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Compile Bundle resources this phase must contain RadioUIButton.m for compile it.[image]